# Latest Hibernate version that supports MySQL 5.6

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa, jakarta-ee

I am currently upgrading my existing project
Changes are:

```
JDK 8 --> JDK 17
JSF 2.2 --> Jakarta Faces 4
Glassfish 4.1 --> 7.0.11
JPA 2.1 --> JPA 3.1
```

I also need to change to change the hibernate version.
Currently, I am using Hibernate 4.3.5.Final

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.5.Final</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
```

I have tried Hibernate 6.1.7.Final, It shows that the minimum Dialect is 5.7.
I may be wrong and have no concrete statement for changes regarding the minimum MySQL version required hibernate version-wise.

My question is,
What is the latest version of Hibernate that supports MySQL 5.6?
Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Out of curiosity (since you're already upgrading a significant chunk of the stack): why not update MySQL? 5.6 is considered end-of-life.

Comment: @Rogue, that is within my plans but I don't want to get to a point I cannot return from. After everything seems stable on production, the next phase will be upgrading MySQL to version 8.

Comment: In that sense, 5.6 was EOL'd on Feb 2021. You're likely looking for a hibernate version on or before that date. If possible, I'd just delay the hibernate update until you've done the MySQL update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checking the sources of `org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect`, one can look for this line

```
private static final DatabaseVersion MINIMUM_VERSION = DatabaseVersion.make( 5, 7 );
```

The link to this code file is here:
https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/6.1/hibernate-core/src/main/java/org/hibernate/dialect/MySQLDialect.java

You can then pick the branch in the github UI and quickly examine what version is supported by each source branch.

The first branch that the `MINIMUM_VERSION` is defined is Hibernate 6.1, and in that branch it defines the minimum version as 5.7.

Hibernate 6.0 does not have this static property. The class comment says it is for "MySQL 5 and above".

Hibernate 5.6 has a class comment that it is for "MySQL (prior to 5.x)".

According to https://hibernate.org/orm/documentation/getting-started/, Hibernate 6.0 is currently end-of-life, and 5.6 is currently on limited support.